# Json data appeard to ;&#1569; if contain arabic words while using post restful web services from html form action

Tags: html, json, rest, spring-boot

Json data appeard  to ; &#1569 ; if contain arabic words  while using post restful web services from html form action

Json result

```
{"messageText":" &# 160 4; & #1573 ;&#1580;& #1585;& #1575;&#1569; &#1571;&#1610 ;&#1617 ;&#1613 ; &#1 605;&# 1605; &#1575; &#1610;&#1604;&#1610; &#1585; &#1583; ","senderName":"sdf","mobileNumbers":"asd","userName":"asd","sectionCount":5}
```

code from my html page

```
<form action="http://localhost:8090/home" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
          <LABEL for="message">message: </LABEL>
          <INPUT type="text" name="messageText"><BR>
          <LABEL for="senderName">Sender Name: </LABEL>
          <INPUT type="text" name="senderName"><BR>
          <LABEL for="Mobile Numbers">Mobile Numbers  </LABEL>
          <INPUT type="text" name="mobileNumbers"><BR>
          <LABEL for="userName">userNames  </LABEL>
          <INPUT type="text" name="userName"><BR>
           <LABEL for="userName">sectionCount  </LABEL>
          <INPUT type="number" name="sectionCount"><BR>


<INPUT type="submit" value="Send">

</form>
```

code from my restful api

```
@RequestMapping(value="/home",method=RequestMethod.POST,headers ="content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public  RequiredInputData  home(@ModelAttribute RequiredInputData require ,HttpServletResponse response) 

    {


        return require;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello it was solved by add this to the header of html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```